# yii2 ajax submit custom form do nothing

Tags: yii2

**hello

i want to submit my form value with ajax
i have a modal in my view file 
in modal i built a custom form to submit my data to a action**

```
<?php

use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;

Modal::begin([
    'header' => 'روز تخمینی برای اتمام پروژه انتخاب کنید',
    'id' => 'modal-accept',
    'size' => 'modal-sm',
    'clientOptions' => [
    'backdrop' => 'static',
    'keyboard' => false,

    ],
]);

?>
<div id="modal-content">
<form method="post" action="<?= Url::to(['admin/site-developer/accept-task'])?>" id="modal_form">

    <?php
    echo jDate\DatePicker::widget([
            'name' => 'datepicker',
            'id' => 'estimate',
        ]);

    ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('submit',['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-success']) ?>
</form>

</div>

<?php
Modal::end();
?>
```

for submit my value and get the result i used this function ,,, but when i click submit no ajax call will perform nothing will happening why i cant see any network activity in my browser inspect ...

```
 $('#modal_form').on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: form.attr("method"),
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
             console.log("successfull");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Something went wrong");
        }
    });

}).on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

any suggestion?

Comment: are you sure is go inside the jquery code? try to put some alert on before and submit, and open "check elements" with your browser and check if there are not jquery error printed and let me know.

Comment: Gabriele Carbonai 
i checked page source i see my script.. 
i put alert before sumbit but it dont alert ... 
i put on submit it alart

in browser console i dont have any error

Comment: but whyy  ??? :|

Comment: check by inspector if you have any jquery code errors

Comment: console log is clear . i dont have any error !  @Gabriele Carbonai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use before submsision, this is the problem

```
$('#modal_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: form.attr("method"),
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
             console.log("successfull");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Something went wrong");
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

Comment: but browser will go to form action address and render  that page i dont want it